# Polymer 2.0 - "this.shadowRoot.querySelector" always returns null

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component, polymer-2.x

I want to create new element and append into `#container` section on `connectedCallback`. I use `this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#container")` to select the element, but it always returns `null`. How can I select the element in the shadow root?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://polygit.org/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="https://polygit.org/components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
</head>

<body>
  <dom-module id="dom-element">

    <template>
        <div id="container">
          <p>I'm a DOM element. This is my shadow DOM!</p>
        </div>
      </template>

    <script>
      class DomElement extends Polymer.Element {
        connectedCallback() {
          this.attachShadow({
            mode: "open"
          })

          console.log(this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#container"))
        }

        static get is() {
          return "dom-element";
        }
      }
      customElements.define(DomElement.is, DomElement);
    </script>

  </dom-module>
  
  <dom-element></dom-element>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Polymer.Element` already attaches a shadow root, so you don't need to do that yourself in `connectedCallback()`. More importantly, your custom `connectedCallback()` must call `super.connectedCallback()` for proper operation. It should look something like this:

```
connectedCallback() {
  super.connectedCallback(); // DO THIS
  // this.attachShadow(...)  // DON'T DO THIS

  console.log('container', this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#container"));
}
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/gWyyQj?editors=1000)

Comment: Thank you @tony19 it work, Polymer official quick tour didn't mention
 that or I miss that, thanks a lot.

Comment: @G.CSun No problem :)